# What would be the proper decision in response for this flag when extracting my Quarkus ZIP file?

Tags: java, path, zip, extract, quarkus

I'm relatively new to Java development. I'm trying to start working with Quarkus, but I'm having some issues when extracting the .zip folder.

Basically, I'm attempting to extract the folder downloaded by quarkusio/quarkus Github repo from my C: drive as you can observe in the picture.

[C: Quarkus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq6qH.jpg) (I renamed the main folder to "Quaku" in order to a resolved issue before this one.

As the extraction reaches 99%, I receive a "Destination Path too long" flag that won't even prompt me the option to "try again", the folder that wants to skip is called "resources".

[Destination Path too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl4gP.jpg)

Should I do something about it? I'll take suggestions. I don't think I should, but I would like to know if this folder is worth to skip, unless it will give me further issues when developing my Quarkus application.

I'm trying to get my quaku.zip (Quarkus) file extracted as I have been doing with a regular smooth .zip extraction.

Comment: Are you trying to build Quarkus itself? (You don't need to do that to be able to write Quarkus applications!) If so, don't download a .zip from GitHub -- install Git and clone the entire repository.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a known limitation of Windows (not quarkus), see [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) for full explanation.

Now problem is identified, you have several solutions :

### Main Workaround

You can enable long path with this command on your PowerShell ([related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)) :

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

### Alternative

As @Ladicek mentioned, you may be trying to build Quarkus from sources (which isn't mandatory at all). If that's the case, prefer cloning repository with git.

If you don't want to build it from source, you still have [Code with Quarkus](https://code.quarkus.io/) which enable you to customize your starter code with dependencies, and create "ready to code" starter which can be unzipped flawlessly (as there isn't this much nested directories, so you are less likely to encounter 256+ character path when unzipping).

Being new to Java, I would advise you to use [Code with Quarkus](https://code.quarkus.io/) as it can also provide example code for each dependency you add to code base.